# Can't update table when POST form is getting it's ID from a previuos GET form

Tags: mysql, forms

On my index.php page I have a form `method='GET' action='new.php'` which gets it's values from a mySQL query.

On top on the new.php page: `$id = $_GET['id']` which retrieves the id from the previuos form in the index.php page. And on the new.php page I also have a form which get it's values through a query with help of `$id` but this time it's a `POST` form thats update a table with a mySQL query.

But the table it's not updating. Why is that? I know that I have all the code right because when I change GET on the index.php page to POST the table is updating.

EDIT:This is the code from new.php

```
require_once('include/connect.php');

 $id  = htmlentities ($_GET['id']);

if (isset($_POST['edit_client'])) {
    if ($_POST['edit_client'] == "1") {
        $_POST['edit_client'] = "0";

        $query3 = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE id='" . $id ."'";
        $result3 = $connect->query($query3);

        $result_rs3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result3)!=0){
            do{
                echo"<form action='' method='POST' class='ajaxform'>
                    <div class='col-md-6 padding0 kundForm'>
                        <div class='controls controls-row left'>
                            <label>Firstname</label>
                            <input type='text' size='22' class='form-control' name='firstname' value='" . $result_rs3['firstname'] . "'>
                         </div>

                         <div class='controls controls-row left marginLeft10'>
                            <label>Lastname</label>
                            <input type='text' size='22' class='form-control span3' name='lastname' value='" . $result_rs3['lastname'] . "'>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class='marginTop20 clear'>
                        <input type='submit' value='Save' class='btn btn-primary btn-danger center-block' onclick=\"return confirm('Save changes?')\"/> 
                        <input type='hidden' name='edit_name' value='1'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id . "'/>
                    </div>

                </form> \n";


            }
                while($result_rs3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3));  
        }
    }

}else if (isset($_POST['edit_name'])) {
    if ($_POST['edit_name'] == "1") {
        $_POST['edit_name'] = "0";

        $id         = htmlentities ($_POST['id']);
        $firstname  = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname   = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['lastname']);


        $query2 =  "UPDATE client SET 
                    firstname         ='" . $firstname .  "', 
                    lastname       ='" . $lastname . "', 
                    WHERE id        ='" . $id . "'";

        $connect->query($query2);
        mysqli_close($connect);  

    }
}
```

Comment: for combined `GET` and `POST` access try `REQUEST`

Comment: No, REQUEST doesn't work.

Comment: The table doesn't update. I don't know why...That's why i'm here :-)

Comment: Show your code atleast, so we might help you

Comment: Updated with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. Screwed up my if-statesment. Changed the `else if{}` to `if{}` and that did the trick!